# Printing Unicode Char inside a List

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

```
a = ['M\xc3\xa3e']
b = 'M\xc3\xa3e'
print a
print b
```

results:

```
['M\xc3\xa3e']
Mãe
```

How can I print `a` like: `['Mãe']`

Comment: Normally you want to print the individual elements, not their representation.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798811/print-list-of-unicode-chars-without-escape-characters

Comment: @Matthias, if that was the case print 'b' would need to print 'M\xc3\xa3e' instead.

Comment: @f.rodriguez: Well, that's the difference between `str` and `repr`. When you print a list `repr` is used for each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature in python2

But in python3 you will get what you want :).

```
$ python3
Python 3.3.3 (default, Nov 26 2013, 13:33:18) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = ['M\xc3\xa3e']
>>> print(a)
['MÃ£e']
>>>
```

or in python2 you can:

```
print '[' + ','.join("'" + str(x) + "'" for x in a) + ']'
```

Answer (score 2):

In python2 you can subclass `list` class and use `__unicode__` method:

```
#Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 16:38:10) 

>>> class mylist(list):
...  def __unicode__(self):
...   return '[%s]' % ', '.join(e.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(e, basestring)
...                             else str(e) for e in self)
>>> a = mylist(['M\xc3\xa3e', 11])
>>> print a
['M\xc3\xa3e', 11]
>>> print unicode(a)
[Mãe, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

For personal use, this module https://github.com/moskytw/uniout will come very handy.