# Printing Arabic/Persian letters in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, nltk

Python doesn't seem to be working with Arabic letters here in the code below. Any ideas?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import nltk
sentence = "ورود ممنوع"

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)

print tokens
```

the result is:

```
>>> 
['\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd9\x88\xd8\xaf', '\xd9\x85\xd9\x85\xd9\x86\xd9\x88\xd8\xb9']
>>>
```

I also tried adding a `u` before the string, but it didn't help:

```
>>> u"ورود ممنوع">>>
['\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd9\x88\xd8\xaf', '\xd9\x85\xd9\x85\xd9\x86\xd9\x88\xd8\xb9']
```

Comment: Have you tried `u"ورود ممنوع"`?

Comment: What's the output when adding the `u"ورود ممنوع"`?

Comment: Exactly the same as when I don't put it there.

Comment: The question is indeed a duplicate. Thanks. I flagged it for deletion.

Comment: That may be the part you're asking about, but there's an additional issue that came up when you started with a `unicode` literal.

Comment: Your problem with `nltk.word_tokenize` in other languages is not with unicode. `word_tokenize` has been designed for English language. For other languages, you might need some modifications on tokenizer. specially with Perso-arabic scripts which has different punctuation characters (e.g. comma: `،`, question mark: `؟`). As you can see they are defined as "Language-dependent variables" in the nltk source code here: http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/punkt.html#PunktLanguageVars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have correct results in list with byte strings:

```
>>> lst = ['\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd9\x88\xd8\xaf',
           '\xd9\x85\xd9\x85\xd9\x86\xd9\x88\xd8\xb9']
>>> for l in lst:
...  print l
... 
ورود
ممنوع
```

to convert it to unicode you can use list comprehantion:

```
>>> lst = [e.decode('utf-8') for e in lst]
>>> lst
[u'\u0648\u0631\u0648\u062f', u'\u0645\u0645\u0646\u0648\u0639']
```

[Printing Unicode Char inside a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947173/printing-unicode-char-inside-a-list/20948167#20948167)

Comment: It *displays* the same, but it is different from what should probably be produced (and certainly from what is expected).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams nltk.word_tokenize splits string by words and we have list of words with byte strings... seems ok to me

Comment: It's taking text and turning it into bytes. That's not its job.

Comment: Hii I got an error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-7: character maps to <undefined>` when trying to print my arabic