# Python nltk cannot tokenize Arabic text

Tags: python, anaconda, nltk, text-mining

When using nltk package to tokenize Arabic text, the results appear as numbers! There is no problem when tokenizing English text.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import stop_words
from stop_words import get_stop_words
doc_a = "ذهب محمد الى المدرسه على دراجته. هذا اول يوم له في المدرسة"
sw = get_stop_words('ar')
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(doc_a)
stopped_tokens = [i for i in tokens if not i in sw]
print(stopped_tokens)
```

When set `tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(unicode(doc_a,"utf-8"))`

Result:

> [u'\u0630\u0647\u0628', u'\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f', u'\u0627\u0644\u0645\u062f\u0631\u0633\u0647', u'\u062f\u0631\u0627\u062c\u062a\u0647', u'.', u'\u0627\u0644\u0645\u062f\u0631\u0633\u0629']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the following code was working for me under python 3.X:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

doc_a = "ذهب محمد الى المدرسه على دراجته. هذا اول يوم له في المدرسة"
doc_a = doc_a.decode('utf-8')
sw = stopwords.words('arabic')
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(doc_a)
stopped_tokens = [i for i in tokens if not i in sw]
for item in stopped_tokens:
    print(item)
```

This line gets you the right stopwords: `sw = stopwords.words('arabic')`.

Comment: the same result :'(

Comment: Are you using python 3.x?

Comment: Python 2.7 using !!

Comment: try out the suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047485/printing-arabic-persian-letters-in-python-2-7

Comment: For me it was working by adding the following line after the definition of doc_a: `doc_a = doc_a.decode('utf-8')` and then printing only one element at a time in stopped_tokens. I modify my answor accordingly.

Comment: yes ,  it was working by adding //doc_a = doc_a.decode('utf-8')

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have stop-words list, I couldn't work on that part, but the tokenization part seems to be working well:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
doc_a = "ذهب محمد الى المدرسه على دراجته. هذا اول يوم له في المدرسة"
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(doc_a)
print(tokens)
```

This was the output I received:

['ذهب', 'محمد', 'الى', 'المدرسه', 'على', 'دراجته', '.', 'هذا', 'اول', 'يوم', 'له', 'في', 'المدرسة']

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7 using !

Comment: in your list you have '.' which is supposed to be a stop word. So it isn't working correctly.