# Handle French characters in list of strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding

I am trying to extract data from a `CSV` file written in French with `Python 2.7`. I can read a single cell correctly (the characters are displayed the way they are supposed to when I print them). However, when I print the list of rows (the entire content of the file), the output is scrambled.

Example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function#, unicode_literals

l = ["à ä â",     #Some french characters
     "é è ë ê",
     "ï î",
     "ù ü û",
     "ö ô",
     "ç",
     "°"]

for i, item in enumerate(l):
    print(l[i])

print(l)
```

Printing the rows separately (`for` loop) outputs:

```
à ä â
é è ë ê
ï î
ù ü û
ö ô
ç
°
```

While printing the whole list (`print(l)`) outputs:

```
['\xc3\xa0 \xc3\xa4 \xc3\xa2', '\xc3\xa9 \xc3\xa8 \xc3\xab \xc3\xaa', '\xc3\xaf \xc3\xae', '\xc3\xb9 \xc3\xbc \xc3\xbb', '\xc3\xb6 \xc3\xb4', '\xc3\xa7', '\xc2\xb0']
```

This is really confusing me. I apologize if I missed a post that already answers that issue.

What I tried so far:

```
l= [unicode(i, 'utf-8') for i in l]
```

Which also outputs:

```
[u'\xe0 \xe4 \xe2', u'\xe9 \xe8 \xeb \xea', u'\xef \xee', u'\xf9 \xfc \xfb', u'\xf6 \xf4', u'\xe7', u'\xb0']
```

## EDIT:

Another attempt was:

```
l=repr(l).decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf8')
print(l)
```

Which outputs the desired result:

```
[u'à ä â', u'é è ë ê', u'ï î', u'ù ü û', u'ö ô', u'ç', u'°']
```

However,

```
print(l[0])
```

Outputs:

```
[
```

So the list is a string now.

Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Time to switch to Python 3 :) I never understood why the representation was different when you have characters in a list vs. printing them alone. IIRC it's something to do with `__repr__` of the list, but I'm just guessing.

Comment: It works without any problem on python 3...

Comment: Try encoding it to unicode and then converting it to raw string.

Comment: I know it works with Python 3 but I'm stuck with Python 2.7

Comment: If you need to use python 2.7, probably it is easier to always loop through the list to get the required result... create your own my_print_list function which loops through the list items and prints them.. guess that's the fastest walkaround

Comment: Try `print repr(l))`. I don't have 2.7 handy to test.

Comment: repr(l) doesn't work.. just tested it.

Comment: I edited my post, `repr(l)` works if you decode/encode it. But the list is converted to a string so I need to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found this feature of Python 2:

[Printing Unicode Char inside a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947173/printing-unicode-char-inside-a-list)

That's just how lists print in Python 2. There's nothing wrong with your data or what you are doing.