# How to print structures with non-escaping backslashes as '\' only?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When printing an array of strings that includes backslash '\', then Python convert non-escaping backslash like in '\.' to '\\.', thus for example:

```
a = ['\.', '\\.', '\n']
print(a)
```

Outputs:

```
>> ['\\.', '\\.', '\n']
```

Is there a way to print `a` so non-escaping backslashes are shows in the short form they are usually written, thus as '\' only?

**Comment about previous answer:**

There is a previous similar question in [Print LIST of unicode chars without escape characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798811/print-list-of-unicode-chars-without-escape-characters).

But the actual structure I try to print is more complex, so it would ease the job if there is some available function to do the formatting, instead of writing it myself as the previous answer suggests.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks; please see update in question.

Comment: No, there is no built-in function, you have to write one yourself. All Python containers show the contents using `repr()`, if you want anything else requires custom formatting.

Comment: Guess I can just do `str(a).replace('\\\\', '\\')` to address the majority of places where non-escaping backslashes as converted to '\\'.

Comment: blind `.replace()` executed on a string representation of a complex data structure is probably the wrong thing to do. What do you want to do with the result e.g., just print on the screen for debugging purposes (then you should leave the output alone)?

Comment: Get your point; the blind replace may be OK for debug purpose, but is not generally applicable for reliable representation of the output.