# python 2.7 print accents inside a list

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8

In python 2.7, I have a list with accented words inside, and I would like to print them well, i.e. I have:

```
>>> a= ['éléphant', 'âge']

>>> print a

['\xc3\xa9l\xc3\xa9phant', '\xc3\xa2ge']
```

I would like to print something like:

```
['éléphant', 'âge']
```

Comment: Does `print 'éléphant'` work?

Comment: The problem may be in the output device (the "screen") which may support a different charset. Do you really nedd to output the strings at screen?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798811/print-list-of-unicode-chars-without-escape-characters