# Encoding error Chinese character with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to scrape the data from a website, but the Chinese characters are not displayed correctly from cmd.

It prints \u7b54\u6848\u9808\ instead of Chinese characters.

This is my code:
(The website encoding is utf-8.)

```
for item in links:
    print (item)
    page = urllib2.urlopen(item)
    #page.encoding = 'utf8'
    page = page.read().decode('utf-8')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page , 'lxml')

    divTag = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "t_fsz"})
    for tag in divTag:
        postData = tag.find_all("td")
        print (postData)
```

I tried different encoding/decoding but I always get the same output. How can I get the correct Chinese characters? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print LIST of unicode chars without escape characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798811/print-list-of-unicode-chars-without-escape-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Python 2, you will need to `encode` the string you `print` for your current output encoding.

We don't know how your system is configured, but you should be able to find hundreds of similar questions -- maybe thrown in your platform and the encoding you use in the search to narrow it down.

If at all possible, I would suggest switching to Python 3 instead.

Comment: Thank you, I switched to Python 3 and I now can see the Chinese characters.